# Is there a way to remove a NIC from the domain profile?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access, nic

I have Windows server 2012 with two Network adapters, one configured with an internal IP and the other one configured with an external IP. When running the remote access configuration Wizard I get the following error: "An external adapter with a public IP address, IPv6 enabled and does not have a domain profile could not be found". I figure if I can remove the domain profile it should let me continue with the wizard since I do have a valid IPv4 public address and IPv6 enabled.

The server has AC/DC, DNS, DHCP and RAS installed. When I look at the connections they both appear in my domain, (these adapters are on one card, not sure if that has anything to do with it or it's because windows set them up that way with the initial installation before I configured each adapter)

Comment: Multihoming a DC is not a good practice, and esspecially to put it on the internet on the second NIC

Comment: Thanks, any recommendations? I only have one Server now.  Can I use Hyper-V and then use a VM as the DC instead?  I uninstalled RAS and reinstalled on a VM  with my current configuration, but now I am having trouble with it joining it to the domain. 
 
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory 
The error was: “DNS name does not exist.”
.
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.local.keiboom.coM